# Create new productpage when new database entry

Tags: javascript, php, database

How can I create a new page when I enter a new product in my database, or hide the parameter inside a normal /.../ ?

In this example I will sell Sandles with the product-id 101010

I do not want to use parameters like in the following example:

```
example.com/shop?productid=101010
```

But I would like the new page to be

```
example.com/shop/sandles
```

Comment: You can also see the product as a user, how would i create a new userpage like instagram does with instagram.com/user

Comment: Have a look at this answer, if you're using Apache: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1304912/mod-rewrite-ecommerce-url-design

Comment: Read about .htaccess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you'll need be able to fetch product not by some numeric ID (101010), but by url segment like this 'my-unique-product-name' (upgrade your server side code)

Now you should have something like this working:

```
example.com/shop?url=my-unique-product-name
```

then add to your .htaccess something like this:

```
RewriteRule ^shop/([A-Za-z0-9-_]+])$ shop.php?url=$1 [L]
```

It tells your server to process URL-s like **example.com/shop/my-unique-product-name** in a same way as **example.com/shop?url=my-unique-product-name**, if that makes sense to you.

Read more about .htaccess URL rewrite [here](https://docs.ovh.com/au/en/hosting/htaccess_url_rewriting_using_mod_rewrite/)

Comment: I see that the works! But unfortunately the rewrite rule is colliding with my other following htaccess rules:

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [NC,L,R]

Options -Indexes

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [NC,L]

How could i fix this?

Comment: Try to put this new rule BEFORE your older rules.

Comment: Putting the rules before the older rules do not work unfortunately, i also tried adding / removing .php after shop which doesn't work either